# Hide two or more attributes over custom layout

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I try to hide two attributes in custom layout, but it works for only one attribute:

```
<reference name="catalog.leftnav">  
<action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
</reference>
```

How can I add here this action:

```
<action method="unsetChild"><alias>manufacturer_filter</alias></action>
```

This way it didn't work:

```
<reference name="catalog.leftnav">  
<action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
<action method="unsetChild"><alias>manufacturer_filter</alias></action>
</reference>
```

Do you know any other solution? I need this only for one category, not generally for all.